# How can I get a word, varied on a number I provide?

Tags: linux, bash

A quick explanation of the problem I'm trying to solve: I have a [.bashrc](https://github.com/theY4Kman/yak-setup/blob/master/.bashrc) and PS1 I like to use on all systems I log into. I have written a [little script](https://gist.github.com/theY4Kman/6197365) to automatically set this up, and hosted it on gist.github, so I can use a one-liner to set everything up. I use [terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) to keep many shells open at once. Lately, I've been keeping open ssh in many of the shells, and it's becoming hard to keep track of which shells are my local box and which shells are other servers.

I want to differentiate between shells. However, I don't want to use the hostname or things like that, because my PS1 is already enormously long.

My proposed solution is to hash the output of ifconfig, use it to retrieve a word from somewhere, then stick the first four letters of it in the PS1. As such, the word provider should have the following constraints: the same number should return the same word every time, and the words provided should vary relatively widely.

Anyone have any ideas, or a better solution? Thanks!

**Edit**: Here's a screenshot of my current PS1 for reference:

[image: My current PS1]

**Edit 2**: Here's a screenshot of my PS1 as of Feb 2018, after splitting the contents onto multiple lines. The "START" lines ensure I can always remember when I ran a command, and how long it took.

[image: ps1]

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... that's an enormously long `$PS1`. Anyway.

Hashing the same value with the same algorithm and no salt will result in the same hash result each time.

```
$ echo -n "123" | md5sum | cut -c 1-8
202cb962
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I want to use memorable words, so not only can I tell the difference between machines, I can also remember which one is which easily. Which is why I want to stay away from using the raw hash.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the hostname then.

Comment: I believe you're right. I think I was really excited about going the complex and roundabout way that I overlooked the uniqueness of hostnames in my situation (such that I can use the first four characters safely). It's not perfect in all contexts, but it's good enough in mine. I still can't shake that feeling of giving up, though :P

Comment: You *could* do something crazy with LDAP or mDNS, but they're massive overkill unless you have hundreds of machines all with "localhost.localdomain".

Comment: As an update, I decided to go with the hostname. To cut down on the size, I'm using 4 characters selected at 4 even-spaced positions. e.g. "the-kids-got-spunk" becomes "tkst", "openvpn-zachtest" becomes "onnc". Pretty sure my math is wrong, but it serves its purpose nonetheless. Thanks for pulling my head out of the clouds.